# Concatenar 2 varchar2 en fecha y hora SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Hola tengo una duda: estoy haciendo unos insert desde una base de datos antigua a una nueva. En la anterior BD hay dos variables varchar2 fecha y hora. En la nueva quiero tener una única variable del tipo 'DD-MM-YYY-HH-MM' ¿como puedo hacer esta inserción?

Si esto es imposible, ¿como puedo hacer el cambio de la variable varchar2 al formato 'HH-MM' y que tipo de variable debería tener la hora?

Answer (score 1):

falta un poco mas de información este proceso lo estas realizando en un procedimiento almacenado o de que manera ?

Cabe señalar que en oracle se concatena de la siguiente forma

SELECT fecha1 || ', '|| fecha2 AS NuevaFecha from table

Comment: Tienes razón Patricio. Aunque lo indica en el título, no sé por qué, lo traté como si fuera SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy fácil, se concatena y listo. 
Por ejemplo el siguiente `SELECT` concatena y deja el resultado en `NuevaFecha`

`SELECT (fecha1 + ', ' + fecha2) AS NuevaFecha`

Pues lo mismo haces con el `INSERT`

Comment: pero como haría la conversión varchar2 a date?

Comment: tendría algo asi : INSERT INTO tablanueva (fecha_hora) SELECT DISTINCT TO_DATE(fecha + hora, 'dd/mm/yyyy/hh/mi') from tableantigua

Answer (score 0):

Como concepto es muy simple, pero despues encuentras formatos distintos de fecha y hora, año de 2 o 4 digitos, dias de 1 o 2 digitos, horas hasta las 12 o 24 horas.
Te paso un consulta con 2 ejemplos que te pueden servir.

```
    select to_date('30-03-2019 00:19:43', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual
    union
    select to_date('30-03-2019'||' '||'00:19:43', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  from dual
```

En la de abajo muestro como concateno la fecha + espacio + hora. Para respetar el formato de salida que defini, este lo puedes cambiar a gusto.